# Calculate how many days

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I wan't to get how long user has staked nft token in days. I recorded `staking` time_stamp while staking and  `un_staking` time_stamp while un_staking. Now I wan't to calculate how many days user has staked for reward distribution based on days. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the general calculation for finding the days.

```
    // Calculate the time difference between unstaking and staking timestamps.
    let time_difference = unstaking_timestamp
    .checked_sub(staking_timestamp)
    .ok_or(DispatchError::from("Timestamp overflow"))?; // Modify error accordingly

    // Convert the time difference to the number of days.
    let days_staked: u64 = time_difference
        .as_secs()
        .checked_div(86400) // T::SECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400
        .unwrap_or(0);
```

Comment: @Immanule John can you please check this code either it is correct or not to convert timestamp into days? https://github.com/Build3rs-Labs/foxies/blob/cb4745624ed2664afe1806e5873533c650fe7943/impls/staking/staking.rs#L222

Comment: Yes it seems so. but it is also recommended to do proper error handling in your code. 1. The checked_sub method returns an Option indicating the result of the subtraction. If the subtraction results in an overflow, it will return None. In such a case, the subsequent operations will not produce meaningful results.

2.The usage of unwrap_or_default() ignores the potential errors or overflow scenarios. In some cases, it may lead to incorrect or unexpected behavior.

Comment: hey @Immanuel John I try to implemented as per you say but when I try to convert time_difference `.as_secs()` as per you suggestion then it gives `no method as_secs() found for type u64`. Here is code for just for calculating days, can you please review it once again. [github_link](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/time_difference_in_days/blob/9ba09eda3a40dd002c96263b28e66b0cd0cdb694/lib.rs#L43)